# Quantifier Logic : Translation of sentence "All students have already done the exam for all course except course X"

Tags: logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

As the title said, what is the best translation for "All students have already done the exam for all course except course X"?
Me and my fellow students debated for quite a long time about this question. We use **x is a domain of students and y is a domain of the courses**, and **Predicate P(x,y) is x already done exam course X**. My answer is $$\forall x \forall y (P(x,y) \iff (y \neq Course X))$$
One of my friend answer is $$\forall x \forall y(P(x,y) \implies (y \neq Course X))$$
and the other answer is $$\forall x \forall y (P(x,y) \implies (y \neq Course X)) \land \exists x(\lnot P(x, Course X))$$
Which one do you think is right? And if none are right, what is the translation and why?

Comment: "We all use the same universe of discourse, in which x is students and y is the courses". No; the universe has "objects"; in order to separate them, we need predicates: $S(x)$ for "x is a student" and $C(y)$ for "y is a course".

Comment: And a **binary** predicate $P(x,y)$ for "x has done y". Thus, "Student x has done Course y" will be $S(x) \land C(y) \to P(x,y)$.

Comment: So, for the easy part: ""All students have already done the exam for all course": $\forall x \forall y (S(x) \land C(y) \to P(x,y))$.

Comment: Sorry, i meant to write P(x,y), x is an universe of discourse consisted of students, and y is an universe of dicourse consisted of courses

Comment: So, you mean something as $\forall x \in S \ \forall y \in C \ldots$.

Comment: Thus, if you name the course $X$ with the constant $CourseX$, you can correctly write: $\forall y \in C (y \ne CourseX)$.

Comment: Yes, that is what i meant.

Comment: If intended that way, I think that $\forall x \in S \ \forall y \in C (y \ne CourseX \to P(x,y))$.

Comment: In first-order logic, the "universe of discourse" is unique; thus, to differentiate the "intended interpretation" of variables, we need either suitable predicates, like $S(x)$, or restricted quantifiers: $\forall x \in S$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  I think it would be great for you to incorporate your comments into an answer.  I, for one, will upvote the answer if you do!

Comment: So we can't just use two domain in a single statement?

Comment: Oh, and if the right answer $(y \ne CourseX \to P(x,y))$
Does that mean the statement "All students have already done the exam for all course except course X" means even if all the students done exam for course X, the statement is still true?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I'm not sure what you mean by "easy part". Do you mean that the full answer including the "except part" should be as in my answer?

Comment: @anthrocoon12: If it's not clear, my answer explicitly addresses your last comment above, because I do not think there is corpus evidence that native speakers use "except" when the stated exception is not in fact an exception. If the "official answer" is as in your comment, then it is **wrong**. Note that the dictionary definition of "except" is "with the exclusion of". "He took everything except this book." **always** implies that "He did not take this book." (at the point it is referring to) in **all** situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $S$ be the domain of students.

And $C:$ be the domain of course tests.

Let  $\text{X-Course}$ be the "name" of the course to be excluded (err, the course that no student has yet taken a test in).

Let $P(x, y)$ denote "$x$ has taken $y$."

---

$$\forall x \in S, \forall y \in C \Big((y \neq \text{X-Course})\to P(x, y) \Big)$$

Or we can say, $$\forall x \in S, \forall y \in (C\setminus \{\text{X-Course}\}) \Big(P(x, y)\Big)$$

where $C\setminus \{\text{X-Course}\}$ is the set of all course tests, except for the test for Course $X$.

$\Huge($ And if you insist on the fact that we are to assume that the domain for $x$ is "All students", and the domain for $y$ is "All courses", with $P(x, y)$ meaning $x$ has taken the test in course $y$, and $X$ the name for the course in which no test has yet been taken,

Then at its simplest, we have: $$\forall x, \forall y\Big(\big(y\neq X\big) \ \rightarrow P(x, y)\Big)\Huge)$$

---

Alternatively, let the domain $D$ of x, y, consist of all persons, places, things.

Let $S(x)$ denote that element $x\in D$ is a student.

Let $C(x)$ denote that element $x \in D$ is a test for an academic course.

Let $P(x, y)$ denote "x has taken y".

Let $\text{X-Course }$ name the "not-yet-if-ever tested academic course X"

Then the sentence you are given can be translated as follows:

$$ \forall x, \forall y\Big(\big(S(x) \land C(y) \land (y \neq \text{X-course})\big) \to P(x, y)\Big)$$

Comment: You've got me, @Jack!  Good question.  Some one (or two) user(s) was/were in a bad mood much earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Definitions:

variables: [($s$: student),($c$: course)]

constant: [$X$: course X]

relation: [$T(s,c)$: student $s$ has taken the exam for course $c$]

Interpretation 1:

$\forall s\forall c((c\neq X)\Rightarrow T(s,c))$.

In words: If a course, $c$, is not course $X$ then students have taken the exam for course $c$.

Interpretation 2(contrapositive of 1):

$\forall s\forall c(\neg T(s,c)\Rightarrow(c=X))$.

In words: If students have not taken the exam for course $c$, then course $c$ is course $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all the existing answers do not accurately convey the same meaning as the original sentence (ignoring the grammatical errors), as interpreted by a native English speaker.

The actual meaning is:

> Every student has taken the exam for every course $C$ that is not course $X$, but there is some student who has not taken the exam for course $X$ (*otherwise we would not say "except $X$"*).

Which translates to:

> $\forall s \in Students\ \forall C \in Courses\ ( C \ne X \to ( \text{$s$ has taken the exam for $C$} ) ) \\\ \land \exists s \in Students\ ( \text{$s$ has not taken the exam for $X$} )$

And I'll leave it to you to finish translating it to pure first-order logic.

Answer (score -1):

$\forall x,y (P(x,y) \iff (y \neq Course X))$ can also be accepted, meaning no one has done exam for $X$ but all did other exams

**EDIT**

$$\forall x \forall y ((y \neq Course X) \implies P(x,y)) \land \exists x(\lnot P(x, Course X))$$
So the other answer you provided is close to being right only it has to switch places in the implication. This means each exam not being $X$ has been done but also fact is that not everyone has done $X$, so there is someone who didn't do it

Comment: If you agree on the "same domain" and we have two student: Jim and John, clearly John $\ne$ CourseX (because John is a person) and thus $y \ne CourseX$ is True. If predicate $P(x,y)$ is "x already done exam y" (I suppose), we have that P(Jim,John) is False, and thus for the pair (Jim,John) the conditional $(y \ne CourseX) \to P(x,y)$ is False. Conclusion:  $\forall x \forall y [(y \ne CourseX) \to P(x,y)]$ is False.

Comment: Does that mean the statement "All students have already done the exam for all course except course X" means even if all the students done exam for course X, the statement is still true?

Comment: Thus, in order to fix it, you can use restricted quantifiers, like $\forall x \in S$, as "suggested" by the OP.

Comment: @anthrocoon12 you're right, it needs a modification, I will add it

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA you miss the point. It is not question about if to put right domains for x and y. He said that x are students and y are exams, no need to restrict them further

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but you are right

Comment: @amWhy my original answer was just like yours, it wasn't excluding possibility that all students have done X-Course exam. But since English language is used by humans, the structure of the sentence itself implies that someone hasn't done that exam yet. Of course the sentence may be part of bigger paragraph like"All students have already done the exam for all course except course X. For course X we are just not sure." In this case your answer would be correct but since there isn't such addition my opinion is that you are wrong.